# How can I convert a python string to an attribute or symbol for assignment?

Tags: python, mocking

So basically, I'm attempting to mock by cheating with eval(). But it doesn't seem to be syntactically viable. Curious if there is any other way? (I'm well aware of mocking libraries for python, please don't suggest that, although any 1-5 line techniques they use, to solve this, would be awesome!)

```
>>> import os
>>> def func(*args, **kwargs):
...   print "Who knows?"
... 
>>> to_assign = 'os.getcwd'
>>> os.getcwd
<built-in function getcwd>
>>> eval('os.getcwd')
<built-in function getcwd>
>>> os.getcwd = func
>>> os.getcwd()
Who knows?
>>> eval('os.getcwd') = func
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

As illustrated above, os.getcwd and eval('os.getcwd') should evaluate to the same thing, but I can't get the assignment to happen if the eval is on the destination side of the statement.

Also, I cannot use exec because I'm using this in a nested function with closures.

A solution for Python 2 is preferable, but also would be good to know a solution for Python 3 if one exists.

Thanks,
Chenz

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)?

```
setattr(os, "getcwd", func)
```

The result of `eval` is a *value* (just like the return value from any other function), and it doesn't make sense to assign to a value in Python.

Comment: In addition to this if you need to get the thing with the attribute by name you can use the "globals()" or "locals()" dictionaries probably: globals()["os"]

Comment: Ok, so use `globals()["os"]` as mentioned above, in combination with `setattr`, and you can do what you need. You will still have to split apart the string `os.getcwd` yourself. This workaround is necessary because you claim to be unable to use `exec`.